# How to build a asp.net website which has code files in a sperate dir

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an existing project, in which the `page.aspx` file has a structure something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="NameSpaceOnCodeFile" 
    Strict="True" Debug="True" %>
```

When I build it, it gives me error the `Could Not Load Type NameSpaceOnCodeFile`.

code files are in separate directory (source/) i.e

```
namespace NameSpaceOnCodeFile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Projcetaname.
    /// </summary>
    public class GuestBook : Proj.Web.Core.Page.BaseBase
    {

        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder abcBook;
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList dbcBook;
                ......
         }

}
```

Can anyone help me how to build/run this website. 
I don't understand the structure

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to check if your "project" is a compiled version or not.

As you say you have files under `/source` that could be the source and what you say that's the project, could be only the deployable version that uses the server code in a compiled `.dll` inside the `bin` folder.

If you check that this is not the case, then you are missing a directive that shows the external code file

```
CodeFile="Source/GuestBook.aspx.cs"
```

so your `.aspx` page directive should look like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="NameSpaceOnCodeFile" 
    CodeFile="Source/GuestBook.aspx.cs" Strict="True" Debug="True" %>
```

unless you have the HTML and Server code in the same document... do you?

Comment: Thank you balexandre, it doesn't have dllz in bin, and i don't miss anything in page directive, actually i have this project from one of my clients, and he wants some upgradations.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your GuestBook.aspx, you will see <%@ Page instructor. Assign your code file path to the CodeBehind attribute.

Comment: Thanks ojlavecd,i have already tried this approach but it doesn't work.